# Avoid 'ambiguous column' in simple PostgreSQL function returning table

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have the following table, function and execution:

```
create table mytable (a INTEGER, b INTEGER);

create function test(q INTEGER)
returns table(a INTEGER, b INTEGER)
as
$body$
begin
    return query select a,b from mytable;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql STABLE;

select * from test(1);
```

I get an 'ambiguous column name' error. I can get rid of it by changing the selection to "select t.a, t.b from mytable t" (per some similar-ish posts). But it seems very odd to have to qualify the column names when there is only 1 table in my query. I'm porting code that has quite a lot of stored procedures selecting from single tables (in various ways) and returning a table with columns that have the same name. Is there a better way than this of avoiding the error, and still having an output table with the same column names?

Thanks for any leads.

Comment: Is the schema of the returned set always the same as the (a) table? Then you could use `...  RETURNS SETOF mytable ...`.

Comment: @stickybit good point, that could cover at least some of them - although part of the reason for defining the stored procedures is to ensure results are independent of underlying future schema changes ... so with that approach, they'd be tightly-coupled again ...

Answer (score 1):

you can (you should) to use aliases.

```
create table mytable (a INTEGER, b INTEGER);

create function test(q INTEGER)
returns table(a INTEGER, b INTEGER)
as
$body$
begin
    return query select mt.a, mt.b from mytable mt;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql STABLE;

select * from test(1);
```

Comment: My question specifically notes this workaround and asks whether there is some way to avoid having to do it, since having to use aliases on a selection with just one table is cumbersome and strange.

Comment: @Peter - inside PLpgSQL is very good technique. Outside PL there is not risk of identifier  collision - so there is not really necessity for using aliases in query with one table. But inside stored procedure with embedded SQL this collision is reality. And it is good reason to use an aliases.

Comment: Unless there is some way in plpgsql for the select statement that follows "return query" to refer to columns in the output table - and if there is, I'd be glad to see an example and a use case - then there should be no possibility of ambiguity/collision, and the parser should not complain about the non-aliased version. I'm not yet seeing any 'good reason' for being obliged to use aliases, here.

Comment: @Peter - in simple stored procedures like this, there is not strong risk of collision, but when you have complex function, then this risk is pretty common - and in the time where plpgsql variables had bigger priority (the collisions was not detected), then this error was pretty bad (really invisible). It was very difficult to find it. More - the stored procedures like this (just envelope on some query) is possible performance anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

maybe thats an option, using format and query execute:
( as the error says, it doesnt know which *a* to take, the pl/pgSQL variable or a columname )

```
create function test(q INTEGER)
returns table(a INTEGER, b INTEGER)
as
$body$

declare
     lsQueryExecute text;
begin

     lsQueryExecute = format('select a,b from mytable');
     return query execute lsQueryExecute;

end;
$body$
language plpgsql STABLE;
```

Comment: This is bad idea. The dynamic SQL is good only when it is really necessary. Elsewhere not - there is big overhead of repeated planning.